# When should I use pool.end()

Tags: node.js, postgresql

When I use `pool.end()` after a query I get the error message "Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined". It seems to me that I shouldn't be using `pool.end` after queries have finished. So when should I use `pool.end()`?

Below is my code snippet:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.PGUSER,
    host: process.env.PGHOST,
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    port: process.env.PGPORT
})

// Display schedule on home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const displaySchedule = `SELECT * FROM schedule`;

    pool.query(displaySchedule, (err, results) => {
        if(err) { 
            throw err; 
        }
        else {
            res.render('index', {schedules: results.rows});
        }
    })

    //pool.end();
});
```

Comment: You should close the connection only when you dont want to perform queries any more. like close/shutdown the server/program.

Comment: So ```const pool = new Pool``` only gets created once and doesn't run again after each request?

Comment: Right. As you can see, you dont create a pool connection for every request. (Your `new Pool` is outside of your get handler. Furthure more, thats bad and a can be pefromance issue. Just keep the connection pool open, pefrom your quier(s) and keep the connection alive. Explizit closing, is in the fewest situaions needed. Even if you close/shutdown your node app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pool.end` [shuts down a pool](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#poolend) completely. In your case - in a web scenario - you do not want do do this. Otherwise you would have to connect to a pool on every new request. This defeats the purpose of pooling.

In your example without calling `pool.end` - you are using the [pool.query](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#poolquery) method. You are all set here and do not have to use any kind of client cleanup or pool ending.

The pool is usually a [long-lived process](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-pool#a-note-on-instances) in your application. You almost never have to shut it down yourself in a web application.

You will have to shut it down - when your are creating pools dynamically or when you are attempting a gracefull shutdown.

For example: in a testing environment, where you connect to a pool before all the features/tests and disconnect after the tests are run, you call `pool.end` at the end on all dynamically created pools.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1670

This issue describes the use of pool.end()